# How to make webcam settings permanent?

Tags: webcam, samsung

With the built-in webcam of my Samsung NP535U3C I have the common problem of the picture looking too dark. I can easily adjust the settings of brightness, contrast, etc. using `guvcview`, but I can't avoid repeating this operation every time I start a new session.

I've noticed that `guvcview` allows me to save the settings in a *.gpfl file. My question is: is there a way to make these settings permanent? Or alternatively, how can I make a script that loads these settings at startup?

The content of my `webcam_settings.gpfl` is as follows:

```
#V4L2/CTRL/0.0.2
APP{"guvcview 1.5.3"}
# control data
#Brightness
ID{0x00980900};CHK{0:255:1:135}=VAL{186}
#Contrast
ID{0x00980901};CHK{0:255:1:33}=VAL{47}
#Saturation
ID{0x00980902};CHK{0:255:1:40}=VAL{69}
#Hue
ID{0x00980903};CHK{-180:180:1:0}=VAL{0}
#Gamma
ID{0x00980910};CHK{90:150:1:128}=VAL{150}
#Power Line Frequency
ID{0x00980918};CHK{0:2:1:2}=VAL{2}
#Sharpness
ID{0x0098091b};CHK{0:128:1:80}=VAL{80}
#Backlight Compensation
ID{0x0098091c};CHK{0:1:1:0}=VAL{0}
#Exposure, Auto Priority
ID{0x009a0903};CHK{0:1:1:0}=VAL{0}
```

Answer (score 8):

This will do the trick:

```
% uvcdynctrl -L webcam_settings.gpfl
```

You can even create this file using the same tool:

```
% uvcdynctrl -W webcam_settings.gpfl
```

Answer (score 1):

The program `guvcview` uses a config file called `.guvcviewrc` in your home directory which controls all of the settings for `guvcview`. Inside you'll see in [this example](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/MicroscopesUSB/VehoVMS001/guvcview_rcFiles/dot_guvcviewrc_video0_2010aug02_1945PM) there is a profile path which defaults to `default.gpfl`

So, save your gpfl file as default.gpfl in your home directory and see if that works, if not, then change the location mentioned in the config file to where your profile file is.